# Predicting time to event based on historic data in python

Tags: python, prediction, forecasting

I Have ATM cash reloading data which has the ATMID and the time at which the cash reloading was done.
Now, Based of the past few Timestamps for a particular ATMID, can we predict the next time the reloading activity will be done?

The Sample Data:

[image]

I know Extrapolation can be used to achieve this, but is there a more efficient method which could capture the pattern and predict the next activity time?

Answer (score 0):

definitely you can predict from this data but accuracy will not too much high for best accuracy you need more data to train your model.

Comment: This is the sample data I've shared, the actual data is more, btw, which method/Algorithm are you suggesting to use?

Comment: You can try 3-4 algorithms of machine learning and check accuracy of each and choose best one...

Comment: For more information please visit https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/how-to-choose-a-machine-learning-model-some-guidelines